# jquery call a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback

i need to execute `posImgCar()` function after after this code

```
$('details_img').click(function(i){
    ...
   $(this).closest(".page").find(".car_detail").parent().attr('href', $(this).attr('src'));
   ...
});
```

so I had this:

```
 $('details_img').click(function(i){
    ...
   $(this).closest(".page").find(".car_detail").parent().attr('href', $(this).attr('src'));
  /*--->*/ posImgCar();
   ...
});

posImgCar();
```

But it just call the `posImgCar()` when I click twice in the same image.

How should I proceed to accomplish it?

Comment: You need to explain what you're trying to do.  The code works exactly as it should.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for jQuery's [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

```
$('.details_img').one('click', function(i){
    ...
   $(this).closest(".page").find(".car_detail").parent().attr('href', $(this).attr('src'));
   ...
   posImgCar();
});
```

From the docs:

> This method is identical to `.bind()`, except that the handler is unbound after its first invocation.

Comment: The OP indicated that he had to click the image twice to get the function called. I'm not sure that unbinding the event handler after the first click is what he wanted. (Of course, I'm not really sure *what* he wanted.) Also, your code sample assumes that 'details_img' is an element with tag name 'details_img'.

Comment: @dgvid - Good catch on the class selector. Regarding what the OP wanted: I thought what he's trying to say is that if clicked twice it'll run again - contrary to his wishes. Maybe I got it wrong (that's why I started the answer with `I think`). The OP should work on his/her English.

Answer (score 2):

In your code example, you were binding a click event handler to `$('details_img')`, which means you were binding it to a custom element, e.g., as if your HTML contained `<details_img></details_img>`. I assume that details_img is actually a class name or and id.

In your code example, you were also calling `postImgCar()` after attaching a click event handler to details_img, presumably when the page loads. If that isn't what you meant to do, then of course take out that extra call.

If you want `postImgCar()` to execute *each time* the user clicks details_img, and after the href attribute is set, do this, if details_img is a *class name*:

```
$('.details_img').click(function(i){
    // ...
    $(this).closest(".page").find(".car_detail").parent().attr('href', $(this).attr('src'));
    posImgCar();
    // ...
});
```

Or this, if details_img is *an id*:

```
$('#details_img').click(function(i){
    // ...
    $(this).closest(".page").find(".car_detail").parent().attr('href', $(this).attr('src'));
    posImgCar();
    // ...
});
```

Finally, if you are using jQuery 1.6 or later, consider using the `.prop()` method, instead of `.attr()`. See the [jQuery API documentation for .prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for an explanation.